# Q.allSettled not returning all the results

Tags: node.js, pseudocode, q, loopbackjs

I'm trying to use [Q.allSettled](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promise-for-array-methods) in NodeJS (LoopbackJS) for the following scenario.

As an input to my method (`REST API`) I get an array of objects. Each of these objects internally has 2 objects: `ObjA` & `ObjB`.

For each item in the array:

If `ObjA` exists in the database get its ID and send mail #1

If it doesn't exist then insert `ObjA` and then get its ID and send mail #2.

Set `ObjA.ID` in `ObjB` and save `ObjB`.

Once all the objects are saved and emails are sent, then send the response of `REST API` call. If any of the previous tasks have failed, add the error details in the response.

Here is the **pseudo code**:

```
myModel.myMethod = function(input, cb){
  var defResp = Q.defer();
  var promises = [];
  try {
    var defObjAList = Q.defer();
    promises.push(defObjAList.promise);

    getObjAIfItExists(input).done(function(inputWIds) { // input[] with IDs populated
      inputWIds.forEach(function(item){
        var defObjA = Q.defer();

        if(item.objA.id){ // objA already exists in DB
          var options = { ... }; // options for sending mail #1
          promises.push(Q.ninvoke(Email, "send", options)); // using loopback Email which internally uses nodemailer
          defObjA.resolve(item.objA.id);
        } else {
          Q.ninvoke(ObjA, "save", item.objA).done(function (savedA) {
            var options = { ... }; // options for sending mail #2
            promises.push(Q.ninvoke(Email, "send", options)); // using loopback Email which internally uses nodemailer
            console.log(promises.length); // prints 3
            defObjA.resolve(savedA.id);
          }, function(err){
            defResp.reject(err);
          });
        }

        var defObjB = Q.defer();
        promises.push(defObjB.promise);

        defObjA.promise.done(function(objAId){
          item.objB.objAId = objAId;
          promises.push(Q.ninvoke(ObjB, "save", item.objB));
          console.log(promises.length); // prints 4
        }, function(err){
          defResp.reject(err);
        });

        console.log(promises.length); // prints 2
        defObjAList.resolve("Process Complete");
      }); // inputWIds.forEach
    }, function(err){
      defResp.reject(err);
    }); //getObjAIfItExists

    console.log(promises.length); // prints 1
    Q.allSettled(promises).done(function (results) {
      console.log(results.length); // prints 1
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results)); // prints result[] with single item
      var response = {};
      response.errors = [];
      // iterate on results and check if any promise was failed, if yes add the reason to errors array
      defResp.resolve(response);
    });

  } catch (err) {
    defResp.reject(err);
  }
  return defResp.promise.nodeify(cb);
}
```

For the testing purpose my input array only contains one item. So the total number of promises that get added to `promises[]` are 4. But in spite of that the result array contains only 1 item.

My code is working for normal case, but if there is an error e.g. while sending mail, I need to send it in response. That is not working because the results array doesn't contain the email sending promise's output.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? And if I need to handle it in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out a way to handle the scenario described above. But I'm still open for alternate approaches.

Instead of resolving `defObjAList` after adding 2nd promise to `promises` array, I'm waiting till all the promises are added to the array.

Then inside the `allSettled` handler (which was monitoring only 1 promise), I again call `Q.allSettled` by passing `promises` array again (which now contains 4 promises). Now this second handler for `allSettled` gets the results array with 4 items for all the promises that were added.

Alternatively I could simple wait for `defObjAList` promise to fulfill and then call `Q.allSettled` for rest of the promises. This will be better in terms of performance. But for the time being I've kept 2 calls to `Q.allSettled`.

```
  :
  :
  inputWIds.forEach(function(item, ind){ // added ind param

    // handle ObjA

    var defObjB = Q.defer();
    promises.push(defObjB.promise);

    defObjA.promise.done(function(objAId){
      item.objB.objAId = objAId;
      promises.push(Q.ninvoke(ObjB, "save", item.objB));
      console.log(promises.length); // prints 4
      if(ind == inputWIds.length-1){ // check if its the last iteration
        defObjAList.resolve("Process Complete");
      }
    }, function(err){
      defResp.reject(err);
    });

    console.log(promises.length); // prints 2
    // defObjAList.resolve("Process Complete"); - removed from here
  }); // inputWIds.forEach

  :
  :

Q.allSettled(promises).done(function (resultsOld) {
  Q.allSettled(promises).done(function (results) {
    console.log(results.length); // prints 4
    // handle results array and send response
  });
});
```